# How can I plot a line/bar for following type of data?

Tags: r, plot

```
b <- data.frame(head=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                ab=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), bc=c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), ca=c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

and so on.

I want to plot (5 individual plots in this case) for different `head` values, e.g. a plot for `a` for different values of `ab`,`bc`,`ca` same for `b` and so on. 
The problem is it's easier to plot this if the table is transposed but difficult in this way. 
Example if the data would have been in this way:

```
b <- data.frame(head=c("ab", "bc", "ca"),
                a=c(1, 4, 2), b=c(2, 5, 3), c=c(3, 6, 4), d=c(4, 7, 5), e=c(5, 8, 6))
```

then it would be simple to plot for `a` with a command `barplot(b$a)`. But how can I plot the same for the data presented in other way as shown in first line.

Comment: I just updated with plotting using your original dataset for multiple plots.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reshape2` to transform the dataset `b` to your expected `b`

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- dcast(melt(b,id.var="head"), variable~head, value.var="value")
d1
#  variable a b c d e
#1       ab 1 2 3 4 5
#2       bc 4 5 6 7 8
#3       ca 2 3 4 5 6
```

Or in this case:

```
 b1 <- t(b[,-1])
 colnames(b1) <- b[,1]
  b1
  #   a b c d e
  #ab 1 2 3 4 5
  #bc 4 5 6 7 8
  #ca 2 3 4 5 6
```

If you want to plot 5 `barplots` on the same window:

```
  library(ggplot2)
  mb <- melt(b, id.var="head")
  ggplot(mb, aes(head, value))+ 
              geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), position="dodge", stat="identity") +
                     theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you need 5 individual bar plots using the original `b` dataset, you could try:

```
  pdf("barplots.pdf")
  apply(b[,-1], 1, function(x) barplot(x))
  dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks it is useful. But can't we plot if the format remains the same without any transformation?

Comment: @Gaurav Chawla If you want 5 different plots using the original dataset, you may have to loop.

Answer (score 1):

'barplot' can be used with original b data.frame:

```
barplot(as.matrix(b[,-1]), beside=T, legend.text=b$head)
```

[image]

For other grouping, transpose the data (as pointed out by @akrun):

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(b[,-1])), beside=T, legend.text=names(b)[2:4], names.arg=b$head)
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the OP wants something like this if it is in one plot window `barplot(t(b[,-1]), beside=TRUE, names=b[,1])` and in the description, it says that he wants 5 individual plots.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have added the transposed version.